# XSLT Sort elements using dictionary

Tags: xslt

I have an XML which is a list of countries with their codes:

```
<Countries>
   <Country Code="DE" />
   <Country Code="FR" />
</Countries>
```

I apply XSLT to this XML to transform into HTML and I want elements to be sorted alphabetically by country name rather than code.

So I defined CountryCodeDictionaryEN variable which is a dictionary of country codes and names. It works fine in `<xsl:value-of />` but not inside `<xsl:sort />`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

<xsl:variable name="CountryCodeDictionaryEN">
    <item key="Germany"
          value="DE" />
    <item key="France"
          value="FR" />
    ... all other countries ...
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="Countries/Country">
            <xsl:sort select="msxsl:node-set($CountryCodeDictionaryEN)/item[@value = @Code]/@key"/>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:variable name="Code" select="@Code"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:node-set($CountryCodeDictionaryEN)/item[@value = $Code]/@key"/>
              </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you post a larger example - so that we have something to test with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item[@value = @Code]` compares the `value` attribute of an `item` against the `Code` attribute *of the same item*.  Since the `item` elements don't have a `Code` attribute, the `select` expression will always result in an empty node set, so every node will get the same (empty string) sort key.  And since `xsl:sort` is stable (items with the same sort key value retain their original relative ordering) the overall effect is no sorting.

You need to use [`current()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current) to "break out" of the predicate and refer to the node being `sort`-ed:

```
<xsl:sort select="msxsl:node-set($CountryCodeDictionaryEN)
                   /item[@value = current()/@Code]/@key"/>
```

This will compare the `value` of the `item` against the `Code` of the `Country`.

Comment: Ran into the exact same situation (sorting on a key) and this is exactly what I needed!